# How to unit test if function has been called? Dependency injection?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, phpunit

I'm creating a simple RESTful API in PHP for practice. I'm trying to write as testable code as possible. After reading many tutorials and watching a few videos, I still feel at a loss on how to design this.

Basically, I have set up a Router class. It is responsible for mapping url paths to controller methods.

It's easy to test the router's state after adding a route.

**But, how do I test if the proper class->function(params) has been called in respond()?**

I'm using PHPUnit, and I've been reading about mocks. I don't know how to use them in this context.

Currently, respond() parses a given path and request method, and calls the mapped method.

Here is my current design:

```
private $routes;

public function __construct() {
    $routes = array();
}

/**
 * Gets all current routes
 */
public function getRoutes();

/**
 * Sets all routes
 */
public function setRoutes($routes);

/**
 * Routes GET request
 */
public function get();

/**
 * Routes POST request
 */
public function post();

/**
 * Routes PUT request
 */
public function put();

/**
 * Routes DELETE request
 */
public function delete();

/**
 * Sets up default paths for a given resource
 */
public function resource();



/**
 * Respond to request
 * @return mixed          JSON of resource data
 */
public function respond($req_method, $request);

/**
 * Returns mapped call info from request method and path
 * @return mixed         An array of the call and params
 */
private function parse($req_method, $request);
```

Comment: Can't you create an instance and wire it to call a TestSpy Controller method (one that records if it is called) ? In your test, you can send a request URL and then check the TestSpy Controller if the right method was called.

Comment: Could you show the method code that you want to test? It would be really simpler to answer your question :) Cheers!

Comment: Well typically one doesn't write code until they've done the test. I'm asking a _design_ question.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have indicated, this would be a good use of a spy or mocking system. PHPunit has some ability to create and test for mocks, but I prefer to use a different library - [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery).

This code will create a class and test that that when you call `average()`, it's called three times, and then also returns a given value.

Your code would call respond(), after setting up a mock that `shouldReceive('get')->once()` (for example). The m::close in the teardown will verify that get() was called, just one time, and would fail the test if it was not.

```
<?php
use \Mockery as m;
class TemperatureTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }
    public function testGetsAverageTemperatureFromThreeServiceReadings()
    {
        $service = m::mock('service');
        $service->shouldReceive('readTemp')->times(3)->andReturn(10, 12, 14);
        $temperature = new Temperature($service);
        $this->assertEquals(12, $temperature->average());
    }
}
```

Since you would be calling a real class to do work in respond(), you will need a '[partial mock](https://github.com/padraic/mockery#passive-partial-mock)'

```
$restful= m::mock('RestfulController[get]');
$restful->shouldReceive('get')->once();
```

Comment: Thanks, Alister. I'm familiar with mocking in both PHPUnit and Mockery. In a way, though, I feel like I could be testing 'too deep' into implementation of the method.

I'm having the same issue when I want to test if a controller interacts with a model.